# How to add threading to the bash script?

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, centos, snmp

```
#!/bin/bash
cat input.txt | while read ips
do
    cmd="$(snmpwalk -v2c -c abc@123 $ips sysUpTimeInstance)"
    echo "$ips ---> $cmd"
    echo "$ips $cmd" >> out_uptime.txt
done
```

How can i add threading to this bash script, i have around 80000 input and it takes lot of time?

Comment: Use a program that process multiple IPs instead of calling `snmpwalk` 80,000 times.

Comment: @chepner, Evidently the OP wouldn't know alternates exist.  The *name* of an alternate program would be more helpful than an allusion to unnamed programs.

Comment: SNMP is a protocol; it is more likely that a custom program using an SNMP library would be more useful than trying to find some other program that fits the use case. The point is, re-running a single-use program many times is almost never the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simple method.  Assuming the order of the output is unimportant, *and* that `snmpwalk`'s output is of no interest *if* it should fail, put a `&&` at the end of each of the commands to background, except the last command which should have a `&` at the end:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while read ips
   do
       cmd="$(nice snmpwalk -v2c -c abc@123 $ips sysUpTimeInstance)" &&
       echo "$ips ---> $cmd" &&
       echo "$ips $cmd" >> out_uptime.txt &
   done < input.txt
   ```
2. Less simple.  If `snmpwalk` can fail, and that output is also needed, lose the `&&` and surround the code with curly braces,`{}`, followed by `&`.  To redirect the appended output to include *standard error* use `&>>`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while read ips
   do  {
       cmd="$(nice snmpwalk -v2c -c abc@123 $ips sysUpTimeInstance)"
       echo "$ips ---> $cmd"
       echo "$ips $cmd" &>> out_uptime.txt
       } &
   done < input.txt
   ```

   The braces can contain more complex `if ... then ... else ... fi` statements, all of which would be backgrounded.

---

For those who don't have a complex `snmpwalk` command to test, here's a similar loop, which prints one through five but sleeps for random durations between `echo` commands:

```
for f in {1..5}; do
    RANDOM=$f && 
    sleep $((RANDOM/6000)) &&
    echo $f &
done 2> /dev/null | cat
```

Output will be the same every time, (remove the `RANDOM=$f &&` for varying output), and requires three seconds to run:

```
2
4
1
3
5
```

Compare that to code *without* the `&&`s and `&`:

```
for f in {1..5}; do
    RANDOM=$f
    sleep $((RANDOM/6000))
    echo $f
done 2> /dev/null | cat
```

When run, the code requires *seven* seconds to run, with this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: It is working good but takes full cpu utilization, any way to reduce it to bit less or can you control the cpu utiiz through code

Comment: @Zeal, Fixed, somewhat.  See `man nice`, also [Limiting processes to not exceed more than 10% of CPU usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151883/limiting-processes-to-not-exceed-more-than-10-of-cpu-usage/193996#193996).

Comment: Thank You!! Linux is very good if you know how it works. I will explore the nice command and the link you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You can send tasks to the background by `&`.  If you intend to wait for all of them to finish you can use the `wait` command:

```
process_to_background &
echo Processing ...
wait
echo Done
```

You can get the *pid* of the given task started in the background if you want to wait for one (or few) specific tasks.

```
important_process_to_background &
important_pid=$!
while i in {1..10}; do
    less_important_process_to_background $i &
done

wait $important_pid
echo Important task finished

wait
echo All tasks finished
```

On note though: the background processes can mess up the output as they will run asynchronously. You might want to use a *named pipe* to collect the output from them.

Comment: I am new to bash and linux, is it possible for you to modify the the above script to include the multi-processing without the loss of output ?